# old encrypted bitcoin wallet keys

Tags: wallet-recovery

I imagine someone has answered this already but i cant find it.
i found a file from 2013, which is my only backup i have of some small amount of bitcoins ...bitcoin-wallet-keys and date.
it seems it is encrypted...long string of characters starting with U.
i downloaded a wallet to try and import it but i can't remember the password. i tried everything i could think of and got message that it couldn't decrypt, check password.

is there any way to retrieve the bitcoins?
thx!

Comment: Yes you can run a password cracker on it. Depending on the length and complexity of the passwords this could take some time or an inifinite number of years. Let me know if you need help with that.

Answer (score 1):

You need the password, otherwise they're gone for good.